# Is $(\mathbb S^3 \setminus \{0,0,0,1\}) \cap \mathbb R^3 $ homeomorphic with $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb R $ ?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Is  $(\mathbb S^3 \setminus \{0,0,0,1\}) \cap (\mathbb R^3 \times \{0\})$ homeomorphic with $\mathbb S^2 \times (\mathbb R \times \{0\}\times\{0\})$ ?; here by

$\mathbb R^3 \times \{0\}$ I mean $\{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb R^4 :w=0\}$ and

$\mathbb R \times \{0\}\times\{0\}:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3:y=z=0\}$ . Please help

Answer (score 0):

Since $(0,0,0,1)$ is not in $\mathbb R^3\times\{0\}$, the intersection is just $\mathbb S^2\times\{0\}\subset \mathbb R^3\times\{0\}$, which certainly *is not* homeomorphic to the other thing (for instance this latter is not compact).

Let's look at $\mathbb S^3\setminus\{(1,0,0,0)\}$ then the intersection is $(\mathbb S^2\setminus\{(1,0,0)\})\times\{0\}$. This is a $2$-sphere minus one point, which is homeo to $\mathbb R^2$ (by steroegraphic projection for instance).

To get $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb  R$, that is, a cylinder, one must drop two points in the sphere, for instance
$$
(\mathbb S^3\setminus\{(\pm1,0,0,0)\})\cap\mathbb R^3\times\{0\}.
$$
This can be seen by projecting in $\mathbb R^3$ the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1, -1<z<1$ onto $\mathbb S^2$ via the radial retraction $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,z)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. This maps homeo the open cilinder over the sphere minus poles.

Finally $\mathbb S^2\times\mathbb R$ is a kind of $3$-dimensional cylinder, homeomorphic to
$\mathbb S^3\setminus\{(\pm1,0,0,0)\}$ via the analogous radial retraction in $\mathbb R^4$ from $x^2+y^2+z^2=1, -1<w<1$.

Comment: could you please show that $(\mathbb S^3\setminus\{(\pm1,0,0,0)\})\cap\mathbb R^3\times\{0\}$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb S^2 \times \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Sorry There was a mistake, I've edited acordingly